# Worklight 6.1 Ant build-app target fails

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a simple HelloWorld type Worklight application, with no adapters and just a 'common' environment. And I am trying to build the application through the build-app target supplied in the worklight-ant.jar file. This target fails with the following stack trace. Any ideas on why this might be happening?

**StackTrace from command line**

```
Buildfile: /Users/jai/Dev/Workspaces/worklight-2014/EFMobile/build.xml
init:
     [echo] Loading ANT Tool

build-app:
     [echo] Building app at /Users/jai/Dev/Workspaces/worklight-2014/EFMobile/apps/HelloEF
     [echo] Worklight Ant Task version 6.1.0.00.20131123-2150

BUILD FAILED
/Users/jai/Dev/Workspaces/worklight-2014/EFMobile/build.xml:26: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.worklight.builder.environment.EnvironmentBuilderFactory.get(EnvironmentBuilderFactory.java:70)
    at com.worklight.builder.ApplicationBuilder.buildEnvironment(ApplicationBuilder.java:268)
    at com.worklight.builder.ApplicationBuilder.buildEnvironments(ApplicationBuilder.java:230)
    at com.worklight.builder.ApplicationBuilder.build(ApplicationBuilder.java:119)
    at com.worklight.ant.builders.ApplicationBuilderTask.execute(ApplicationBuilderTask.java:112)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed creating resourcesRootFolder
    at com.worklight.builder.environment.EnvironmentBuilder.initResourceFolder(EnvironmentBuilder.java:199)
    at com.worklight.builder.environment.EnvironmentBuilder.<clinit>(EnvironmentBuilder.java:192)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Resource not found: jslibexpanded.zip.MD5
    at com.worklight.builder.util.BuilderUtils.unzipResourceIfRequired(BuilderUtils.java:723)
    at com.worklight.builder.util.BuilderUtils.initResourcesFolder(BuilderUtils.java:704)
    at com.worklight.builder.environment.EnvironmentBuilder.initResourceFolder(EnvironmentBuilder.java:197)
    ... 23 more

Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 1):

may be your ant is older than the prerequisite version ?

```
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=66C745D01E8711E28ACF6F870925FE36&osPlatform=Linux#!
```

regards

Comment: Thanks. I do have the latest version of ant - 1.9.3.